# System restart to windows using objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, operating-system, osx-mountain-lion

If a users wants to reboot to windows from OS X, he/she either needs to:

- a) Reboot holding down the ALT key and select windows
- b) Go to `System
  settings` -> `Startup disk` -> `Select windows` -> `Reboot`

*(Given that the user has a bootcamp partition and windows installed).*

Since I now and then play some games, and prefer doing that directly in Windows and not using e.g. VMWare Fusion. I would like to develop a smarter and easier way of rebooting. I know how to reboot a machine using Objective-c, but how can I choose the boot partition and reboot to it? Basically how the system restart function works in the system settings (choose partition and reboot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a programmatic interface, but you can set the startup disk with the `bless` command, see "man bless".

Comment: Found this page, thanks to your suggestion which helped me out: http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2010/01/reboot-into-bootcamp-script-applescript-app.html